# how to interact with a command line program from c++ code

Tags: c++, sql, command-line

For my computer science class final project, I need to interact with a SQL database. Only problem is, my prof won't install the SQL c++ API for me. Is there a way I can still interact with SQL without the API?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post a code snippets to show what have you tried and error log .

Comment: What platform are you using? Linux?  Windows? Mac?  Something else? Is the database local or remote?

Comment: Does the assignment actually require a SQL database?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting help, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want your program to be able to launch a child process (an SQL command line program in this case), and then be able to read the text it receives from the child process's `stdout` and/or `stderr`, and write text to the child process's `stdin`, the same way a user would if he/she were running that program interactively.

The answer is yes, it is possible to do this, although it takes some work.  Under Linux/Unix/MacOSX, you can call [forkpty()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) to spawn a child process -- the parent process will get a socket (via `forkpty`'s first argument) that you can use to communicate with the child process's stdin and stdout.  In the child process, you can then call [execvp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) (or one of its variants) to run the SQL program in that process;

Under Windows, it's a bit more complex -- you'll need to set up some pipes and then call CreateProcess() to launch the child process, and communicate with it through those pipes.  Microsoft has a page on the topic (including example code) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).